# Receiving "Index Out of Range Exception" when trying to pull data from a database

Tags: c#, sql, backend, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm new to backend development and trying to pull quotes for a testimonial page. Currently my code is resulting in the following error message on my site:

System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Blurb at
System.Data.ProviderBase.FieldNameLookup.GetOrdinal(String fieldName) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name) at
testimonial_Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\UserFiles\testimonial\testimonial.aspx.cs:line 49

Here is the code that's resulting in this

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //BlurbID = Session["Blurb"];
        Page.Title = "Testimonials";

        try
        {
            sqlConnectionStr.Open();
            SqlCommand getBlurb = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT b.BlurbText, b.BlurbID
FROM TestimonialBlurb b ", sqlConnectionStr);

            getBlurb.Parameters.Add("@BlurbID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
            getBlurb.Parameters.Add("@BlurbText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = "This is a Blurb";
            using (SqlDataReader blurbReader = getBlurb.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (blurbReader.Read())
                {
                    blurbPH.Controls.Add(new Literal
                    {
                        Text = blurbReader["BlurbText"].ToString() + "<strong>" + blurbReader["Blurb"].ToString() + "</strong>"
                    });

                    if (blurbPH.Controls.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Response.Write("There are currently no testimonials available.");
                    }



                }
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            blurbPH.Controls.Add(new Literal
            {
                Text = ex.ToString()
            });
        }

        finally
        {
            sqlConnectionStr.Close();
        }



    }
}
```

I'm thinking I need perhaps some sort of DECLARE statement at the beginning of my SQL query -- if anyone could point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Does it work if you _don't_ have `DECLARE` in your SQL command, and the "@" before Select?

Comment: Your SQL query isn't returning `Blurb`, it's returning `BlurbText` and `BlurbID`

Comment: You have `b.BlurbID` in SQL statement but you are trying to read `Blurb` from reader. That's why you are getting error

Answer (score 1):

This is your sql query:

```
SELECT b.BlurbText, b.BlurbID
FROM TestimonialBlurb b
```

So you have two columns `BlurbText` and `BlurbID`. But you ask for column `Blurb`:

```
blurbReader["Blurb"].ToString()
```

So maybe you want to replace this with `BlurbID`. Apart from that, why you add two sql-parameters at all if you have a select query without parameters?